# In Jmeter bean shell preprocess is there any way to read the lines of CSV data file and put into an array

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter bean shell preprocess is there any way to read the lines of CSV data file and put into an array
csv file contains
data1 
date2
date2
i want put all three values in to array and send to Http request in jmeter for for each controller

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can write regular java code to open, read and parse files in a beanshell element. Try looking up CSV file reading in java.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the Beanshell

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path.to.your.file.csv"));
int counter = 1;        

for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
    vars.put("date" + counter, line);
    counter++;
}
```

However I don't see any value added by Beanshell here, it is recommended to avoid scripting and use JMeter components where possible. If you need to send values from CSV file consecutively I would recommend using one of the following test elements instead:

- [CSV Data Set Config](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config)
- [CSVRead](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [StringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) functions